# How to alter the owner/authored by field to the current user when using quick_node_clone

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

Using Drupal 8 with [quick_node_clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/quick_node_clone) module.

When a node is cloned I need to change the 'owner' or 'authored by' value to the person who is cloning the node.

There is an opportunity of manually changing this but I need to automate this. 
I am have been trying the `hook_form_alter` with some alternatives, see the commented out section, without success.

```
function quick_node_clone_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

 print_r($form_id);  

 if ($form_id == 'quick_node_clone') {
  // change author
  //$form['author']['name']['#value'] = $user->uid;
  //$form->setOwnerId($current_user);
  //$form->uid = $user->uid;

  print_r($form['field_author']['nid']['nid']['#value']);  
  global $user;    
  $form['field_author']['nid']['nid']['#value'] == $user->uid;
 }
}
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need a presave hook rather than an alter hook...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function customModule_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $current_user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  $entity->setOwnerId($current_user_id);
}
```

**Edit**
You would be better to check on your content type:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function customModule_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $current_user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'your_content_type_name'){
    $entity->setOwnerId($current_user_id);
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but it doesn't seem to get the current_user_id into the Authoring Information Authored by field. And yes cache was cleared. Just to be clear for my understanding also. This is meant to trigger when the clone button is clicked. How does that trigger the _presave?

Comment: i tested it works, for me, you did dump the $current_user_id variable its correct ?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something @berramou and appreciate your help. Here is what I have done. 1) in mymodule.module file I added this to the top `use 
\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface` 2) then added the code as you have it replacing customModule with mymodule. 3) Cleared cache and visited the admin/content page and from the edit Operations selected clone. 4) A cloned copy is created but the Author Information is still the original author. What am I missing? What did you mean by dump.

Comment: in this hook print the `$current_user_id`  just to see if the function executed and you get the right user id ? if you use devel you can use `dpm($current_user_id);`

Comment: i think the original other of the node you clone is the current user that's why you don't see the change.

Comment: again appreciate @berramou help. I don't believe that I am calling the right hook. I don't get any return for dpm($current_user_id); And since that is outdated I also tried kint($current_user_id); die(); but get nothing returned. I also tried a simple echo "can you see this"; to no avail. It does seem as though I am calling the wrong hook.

Comment: I would click clone and view the content the authored by in the admin/content path does not update with the currentUser so would go back and start again. BUT if you click save it does update. No wonder I couldn't see results and you could! Thanks that part does work.   But, it still is a bit confusing if the editors check the authored by field. First prize would be to update the 'preview' authored by field. Is there a hook for that?